# What does hydrate mean on Twitter?

Tags: twitter

In the Twitter API there is a status_lookup method that "hydrates" a tweet. The docs are unclear about what this means. So when do I need to hydrate a tweet?

If I have tweets from `/statuses/user_timeline` why would I need to hydrate them?

Please provide an example before and after of normal tweet and hydrated tweet and explain the difference.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the docs: 
  "This method is especially useful to get the details (hydrate) a collection of Tweet IDs."

HYDRATE = get complete details (i.e. fields) of a tweet.

Many Twitter API calls that return tweets do not return all the fields. So, `statuses/lookup` may be used as a secondary call to get these fields.

For example, `search/tweets` may return tweets that have embedded video, but it will not return the URL of the embedded video. So, a second call to `statuses/lookup` is required to get the video.